# Changing datetime output to say Today and breaking off the time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

If I have following code that I output items from my database. I was wondering how I can check to see if something had the same date as today, then the outputted data would echo out 'Today' instead of 7-23-15, the same goes for 'Yesterday' if I was looking at something posted yesterday.

Then I wanted to see if I can break off the time part of a datetime entry in a database and only echo the time?

I have DATETIME as my datatype in my database.

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT `id`, `category_id`, `topic_id`, `post_creator`, `post_content`, `post_date` FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
    if($stmt2===false) {
    die();
    } else {
        //var_dump($stmt2);

            $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->store_result();
            $stmt2->bind_result($post_id, $post_category_id, $post_topic_id, $post_creator, $post_content, $post_date);
            //$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
            if (!$stmt2) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
            }
        }
    $num_rows2 = $stmt2->num_rows;
    if($num_rows2) {
        while($stmt2->fetch()) {
        $post_id;
        $post_category_id;
        $post_topic_id;
        $post_creator;
        $post_content;
        $post_date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP function accepts a Unix timestamp and returns it in the format you wanted:

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {

    $strFormat = 'Y-m-d';
    $intTimeStamp = strtotime($strDateTime);
    $strDate = date($strFormat, $intTimeStamp);
    $strTime = date('H:i', $intTimeStamp);

    if($strDate == date($strFormat)) {
        return "Today " . $strTime;
    }
    elseif($strDate == date($strFormat, strtotime('yesterday'))) {
        return "Yesterday " . $strTime;
    }
    else {
        return $strDate . " " . $strTime;
    }

}
```

Now, when you want to use your date for something, like ouputing it, instead of

```
echo $post_date;
```

you do

```
echo fixDate($post_date);
```

If you want it in another format than `YYYY-MM-DD`, just change the value of `strFormat`. The relevant part of the PHP documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: How could I make this work in my actual code though?

Comment: I have the datetime datatype set for it

Comment: The function? Don't place it inside a class or another function or something. But apart from that, no. If you want to keep things tidy you could place it in an included file together with other utility functions.

Comment: I get this error for the function fixDate line `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) `

Comment: Have been writing JS all day... Sigh. Fixed it.

Comment: No worries. I get this error now... `Fatal error: Call to undefined function dateFix()` for `dateFix($post_date);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84115/discussion-between-anders-and-paul).

Comment: I tried to put `dateFix($post_date);` in my while fetch loop and then I changed it back to it's normal $post_date, and then put `dateFix($post_date);` later in the page and echo it, but both occurrences gave errors.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT `id`, `category_id`, `topic_id`, `post_creator`, `post_content`, `post_date` FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
```

with:

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT `id`, `category_id`, `topic_id`, `post_creator`, `post_content`, IF(DATE(`post_date`) = CURDATE(), 'Today', DATE(`post_date`)) FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
```

This will return only the date portion. If it is the current date, it will return 'Today'.

Comment: Would this make it say yesterday then? `IF(DATE(`post_date`) = CURDATE()-1, 'Yesterday',`...Then based on how you are structuring that, would this make the time read by itself? ` TIME(`post_date`)`....Would I have to add in new bind_params and bind_results because of adding things in the SELECT query?

Comment: Paul, no that will not work. You'll want to see DATE_SUB() at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I did this and the query died.. ` IF(DATE(`post_date`) = CURDATE(), 'Today' OR (DATE(`post_date`) = CURDATE()-1, 'Yesterday', DATE(`post_date`))`

Comment: Also since it seems like I can't split up the time from it and put the time somewhere else, how can I get this to show both again?

Comment: You can simply put the original `post_date` back into the query (just after `post_content`), then add an additional binded variable in you PHP code called 'formatted_date' or something similar.